# MAC addresses in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, sockets, ip-address, mac-address

I have a function that loops through available ip addresses on a router and returns the ones that have a defined port open (puts them in an array).
Is there a way I could get the mac addresses of the returned ips too?

I got the looping function from here on StackOverflow and made some modifications. This is it:

```
var net = require('net'), Socket = net.Socket;

var checkPort = function(port, host, callback) {
    var socket = new Socket(), status = null;

    // Socket connection established, port is open
    socket.on('connect', function() {status = 'open';socket.end();list.push(host);});
    socket.setTimeout(1500);// If no response, assume port is not listening
    socket.on('timeout', function() {status = 'closed';socket.destroy();});
    socket.on('error', function(exception) {status = 'closed';});
    socket.on('close', function(exception) {callback(null, status,host,port);});
    socket.connect(port, host);
}

var LAN = '192.168.0'; //Local area network to scan
var POI = 80; //Port of interest

var hostList = [];

//Scan over a range of IP addresses and execute a function each time the port is shown to be open.
for(var i=1; i <=255; i++){
    
    checkPort(POI, LAN+'.'+i, function(error, status, host, port){
        if(status == "open"){
            console.log("Reader found: ", host, port, status); 
        }      
    });     
}
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(hostList)
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Assuming net.Socket refers to https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket then my guess would be no. As stated: "This class is an abstraction of a TCP socket". TCP belongs to the transport layer of the OSI model, whereas MAC addresses belong to the data link layer. (See OSI model for more details https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)

Comment: Thanks very much. But is there a module I could use outside of the net socket that would allow me to maybe use the ips I got to get the MAC addresses?

Comment: Perhaps look into PCap and associated wrappers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272383/capturing-packets-with-nodejs-on-windows) - I've successfully used PCap (in my case it was the SharpPCap wrapper)

Comment: Alright. Thanks!